# In highchart, after giving unequal tickPositions how to keep grid lines position equal?

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to set customise y-Axis in highcharts, where i have data count in two digits and more than 6 digits too, i have set y-axis tickPosition according to my need like [0,50,500,5000,50000,500000]. But i want the spacing between my grids equal.

[My Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RSmW.png)

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: 'Custom tick positions'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'through axis.tickPositions and axis.tickPositioner'
    },

    xAxis: {
    },

    yAxis: {
        tickPositions: [0, 50, 500, 5000,50000,500000]
    },

    series: [{
        data: [
            [0, 5000],
            [1, 422102],
            [2, 93210],
            [3, 45111],
            [4, 12]
        ]
    }]
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/tickpositions-tickpositioner/

In above link example, I dont want that extra spacing after 2 in x axis, i want those space to be equal. in my case it will also be helpful in y-axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [yAxis.type](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.type) and convert the tick into a log scale:

```
yAxis: {
    type: 'logarithmic',
    tickPositions: [0,50,500,5000,50000,500000].map((v) => Math.log10(v)) // Used to convert the numbers in logarithmic scale
},
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/14jn2svo/)

Comment: Thanks @Core972. Solution is perfect.